# Android Lollipop device does not show bottom buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made layout which has buttons at bottom part:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="my.site.com.myapp.fragments.NewsFragment">

<!— TODO: Update blank fragment layout —>

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/newsListView"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

<Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="All Events"
 android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllEventsButton"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

<Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllSharesButton"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Shares"
 android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Android 4.1 able to show bottom buttons while Android 5.1 does not.

[image: Android 5.1 and Android 4.1]

On the left side Android 5.1 on the right side Android 4.1.

Does Android 5.1 requires additional configurations on layouts? If it is feature of new versions, then it is bad feature.

The main problem is that If this layout is placed on Activity it shows buttons. However it fails to show in Fragment

Comment: Why you set two properties : android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" in listview ?

Comment: Does it has influence in my problem? When I placed listview it automatically added them.

Comment: Remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from list.

Comment: your code is working fine in Android Lollipop ##5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.site.com.myapp.fragments.NewsFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllEventsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:text="All Events" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllSharesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:text="Shares" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you have two `ids` in `linear layout`?

Comment: I have used your code. Now there only white line appears but without buttons.

Comment: check now and preview it, it shows perfectly in my studio.

Comment: I have created empty project. Then used your code. It worked. However, inmy own project it does not show buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I have to fix your layout replace your xml with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.site.com.myapp.fragments.NewsFragment">


        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All Events"
            android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllEventsButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllSharesButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Shares"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/newsListView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have replaced my xml and nothing changed.

Comment: It works when Android is 4.* but not when Android is 5.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.site.com.myapp.fragments.NewsFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsListView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All Events"
                android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllEventsButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fromNewsToAllSharesButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Shares"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my output :

[image: Output]

Comment: I have replaced my xml by yours. Nothing changed

Comment: Is it Fragment or Activity? In Activity it works but des not in Fragment

Comment: Try to Create Fragment and test your layout in it.

Comment: sorry dude i quit . do it yourself i have another work

Comment: you have to mention earlier in question